# Codium and Nautilus crashing at boot with Signal 5 and SIGSEGV errors

Tags: boot, nautilus, segmentation-fault, logs

Shortly after boot, I am getting a message "System program problem detected. Do you want to report the problem now?" when I click "Report problem" I get 2 pop-ups (attached screen shot). One is for Nautilus and one is for VS Codium.

Based on other similar questions I found, I did run

```
memtester 1024 5
```

But it found no errors, everything checked as OK.
I do not know how to pull all the data from these screens other than  manually typing it all out. Here is what I saw that looked relevant, and I added screen shots below. If you need more details, I will need to know where to find them.

```
Nautilus:
Title: Nautilus crashed with SIGSEGV
SegvReason: reading NULL VMA
Signal: 11
```

For Codium I don't see any related Reason details for this other than:

```
Codium:
Title: codium crashed with signal 5
UnreportableReason: This does not seem to be an official Ubuntu package. Please retry after updating the indexes of available packages....
```

[Nautilus and Codium crash errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Ojb.png)